# Is there a relationship between Transonic, Mystique, and Apocalypse?

Tags: marvel, x-men

One of the "Five Lights", [**Laurie Tromette**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transonic_(comics)) (codename: Transonic) is one of the new mutants who got her powers after the whole "[House of M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_M)" story arc. After her powers were activated, she permanently resembles the love-child of existing characters Mystique & Apocalypse. She even has the ability both characters share - the ability to shape-shift her physical form, albeit in a limited fashion. She can also fly, an ability often used by Apocalypse. Did I mention she runs around naked, just like the movie version of Mystique?

[image]

I've looked up the character, but I'm not really caught up on the X-Men stuff within the past few years. I didn't see any indications on her profile that she was anything other than what she appears, but you never know if those are complete.

**Given the complicated relationships of the X-Men universe, are the abilities and appearance of Transonic an indication of any relationship between her, Mystique, or Apocalypse?**

Comment: to my memory, her appearance in that particular image is way more apocalypse-like than she is normally drawn. i don't recall her really having much of a revealed background, but given that they already had [kid-apocalypse](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/En_Sabah_Nur_%28Evan_Sabahnur%29_%28Earth-616%29) running around, i don't think they would have another one popping up just yet

Comment: She appears frequently in the Schism paperback, and that's how she appears there as well, including the lines on the face. You're probably right, though.